# The nature of an action that leaves something as it was before

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

E.g. entering the kitchen, preparing food, and leaving a mess; or entering the kitchen, preparing food, and leaving everything as it was before.

How do you call this concept? "I take some actions, but after I am done, everything is the same". This also applies that you can repeat the exact same action.

EDIT:
I feel this concept in my current living situation. For the week I live in an Airbnb apartment in a different city, and when I come home on the weekend, I could get a dismissal any day and I would not have to "clean up after myself", as opposed when I had a rented flat in the city.

Comment: It's called *cleaning up after yourself*. Related: [What is the meaning of the phrase “clean up after” and when and how to use it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4774/142322)

Comment: Could you use 'leaving no footprint' or 'seamlessly'?

Comment: In English, we normally ask: [What do you call...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324568/how-do-you-call-vs-what-do-you-call)? Please edit your post, and spread the word :)

Comment: a single word request for this ? may be a tall order.  consider adding a  phrase request too

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics or computer science, the most common term for this property is [*idempotence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), and an action (or mathematical transformation, or computer program) is said to be *idempotent*.

Technically, the term means "the ability to be performed repeatedly without changing anything".

I've not heard the word used outside of those contexts except as a joke.

Comment: I feel like idempotence is different because there is an initial change. E.g. `setNumberTo5(x)` is idempotent, but there is an initial change. I just means you can apply it multiple times without any further change.

Comment: That's a good point, especially with regards to math.  In computer science, though, the term generally means "causes no change", even on the first try.  For example, in software design, a good _unit test_ is always idempotent - after running, it leaves the system in the same state it had prior to running the test.

Comment: "left (or finished or exited) without leaving a trace."

Answer (score 0):

A functional term I have come across, which describes this notion is:

"without side effect"

The world is the same when you started the action, as it was before. Of course that's not really the case, but it feels like it.

EDIT:
Another phrase I've come across, and which describes this situation is "with a clean slate".
E.g. "Every week I start with a clean slate."